# what does "underlying App Service deployment doesn’t support PremiumV2" mean?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Ive looked around and cant understand it or find anything.

I have two app services deployed with their own associated app service plans.

they are deployed with terraform so follow the same process and parameters except for the name.

so why would one app service not be allowed to upgrade to P1V2 app service plans and the other can?

both are deployed to in the same way and the line from Microsoft, " underlying App Service deployment doesn’t support PremiumV2 " doesnt help much as I dont know what that means.

Any one?

Bueller?

Comment: You can refer to this document about [Get started with Autoscale in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/autoscale-get-started).

Comment: The problem you encountered seems to have nothing to do with technology, because one can succeed and the other fails. So I suggest you raise a support ticket in portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Services are deployed to what's called scale units. The newer scale units support Pv2 instances while older ones do not. The recommendation to make sure your app service plan lands on a scale unit that supports Pv2 is to deploy an ASP with Pv2 SKU and then scale down.

[Scalue up from unsupported tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-configure-premium-tier#scale-up-from-an-unsupported-resource-group-and-region-combination)
[Architecture including describing scale units](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/february/azure-inside-the-azure-app-service-architecture#global-and-geo-distributed-architecture)